# Referencing and inserting into a vector of list<nodes>

Tags: c++, list, vector, hash, hashtable

I am implementing a hashtable and am having trouble with the implementation. After literal hours of googling on this one thing, i've  given up and was hoping to see of i could get any help here. The biggest issue is to do with the use of vectors in the HashTable(doesnt make sense to me, rather just use list<> but using it is required)

My main issue is to do with how to implement the insert function to add to the HashTable.

```
void HashTable::insert(ulint key,ulint value){  //insert data associated with key

   HashNode nodeToAdd;
   nodeToAdd.assign(key, value);

   int index = hash_function(key);

   this->table[index].push_back(nodeToAdd);

   }
```

Now the issue im having is adding the HashNode to my HashTable.

for reference in HashTable, the field for the table is

```
typedef vector <list<HashNode> > Table;
Table *table;
```

So by my understanding

```
   this->table[index].push_back(nodeToAdd);
```

is going to the vector HashTable[index], which at the index should be a list. and when it gets to that list, it should push_back the new node into the list.

However when compiled, i'm hit by an error(no matching function to call) and i don't understand why.

Comment: Any C++ code that uses `malloc()` is broken. `malloc` is for C code. Even if `HashNode` is a POD, `new` should be used. Otherwise, some innocent non-POD member gets added to `HashNode`, later, and you'll start wondering why all these mysterious crashes started to happen, all over the place. Finally, the correct way to handle compilation errors is to try to understand what they mean, instead of running Google searches for `how do I do X`.

Answer (score 0):

Your list stores objects of type `HashNode`, *not* type `HashNode*`.

So you need to decide which of those you want to use, and change the code accordingly.

1. If you want to keep storing `HashNode`, then your `insert` is wrong -- it should instead create the node on the stack and store it by value in the list.
2. If you want to store a pointer, then your `Table` type is wrong, and should instead be `vector<list<HashNode*>>` -- note it should be managed carefully since the pointers will not be automatically deleted.

Personally, I'd suggest you go with #1 and save yourself a whole lot of headaches.  But if you insist on #2, then I suggest you stop using `malloc` and use `new` -- or better yet use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` for automatic lifetime management.

Also noteworthy is your definition `Table *table`.  This is baffling, since `Table` is a vector.  Your `insert` function is dereferencing this pointer, expecting it to perhaps point to an array of `Table` values, when it's quite clear you actually think it's a vector.  I'm pretty sure you don't want that to be a pointer.

Since I only just noticed that detail, I imagine that's the *first* source of your error, since `table[index]` is actually type `Table`, not type `list<HashNode>` and you were trying to call the non-existent function `vector<list<HashNode>>::push_back(HashNode*)`.

Comment: Unfortunately im forced to use the class defs given, so have to use Table *table. Maybe its me misunderstanding typedef but doesnt the typedef line make "Table" equivalent to vector<list<HashNode>> ? So i would think Table *table is of type vector<list<HashNode>> ?

Comment: 1) Yes; 2) No!  `Table*` is a pointer, so it's equivalent to `vector<list<HashNode>>*`